# State Diagram Generator

Tags: c++

Is there a tool which generates the state space by seeing the code. i.e., if I give a class definition, it should generate the state machine.

EDIT: State machine I mean is just the graphical representation of the classes and state changes.

Comment: Isn't it usually infinite except in some cases?

Comment: Only in some cases it is infinite

Comment: It's rarely actually infinite.  It is almost always far greater in number of states than anything we can actually deal with.

Comment: It's theoretically inifinite if there's at least one member of type string, list, vector, etc - any container really.

Comment: Good point.  I was thinking of implementations rather than the language itself.  However, since string::size() returns a value of a specific type, could an integral type hold an infinite number of values?

Comment: A class is also a strange thing to want a state space for: usually, if you are looking for state evolution, you really need a functional expression of an algorithm or protocol, where control flow is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific.

The state space of a class is the Cartesian product of the state space of each component, and it doesn't take a particularly complicated class to have more possible states than there are protons in the Universe.  With a few exceptions, C++ code is not well suited to analysis with state space.

State machines are usually associated with regular expressions.  Do you want a tool that does something with a regular expression?

If so, what?  Languages that accept regular expressions do something to convert them to a form of state space representation, leaving it in some sort of internal form.  Do you want it in the form of a readable diagram, as the tag implies?

Answer (score 0):

Many classes have infinite numbers of states, so creating the statemachine would be infeasible... For example, there is no DFA for palindrome, so any class which accepts palindromes won't have a usable state diagram...